# Cannot find type definition file for 'cucumber' in Protractor with Cucumber Typescript framework

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

I am working on Protractor with Cucumber and TypeScript. I am facing the following issue. How to solve the following error:

```
 Cannot find type definition file for 'cucumber'.
 The file is in the program because:
 Entry point of type library 'cucumber' specified in compilerOptions
 tsconfig.json:13:22
 13 "types": ["node","cucumber"],
 File is entry point of type library specified here.
```

Here is my tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",                          
        "module": "commonjs", 
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,   
        "sourceMap": false,  
        "removeComments": false,   
        "outDir": "JSFiles",                        
        "types": ["node","cucumber"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,                   
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error Resolved , To resolve this install @types/cucumber module in your framework
But even if this does not resolve that means "index.d.ts" file under node-modules/types is missing , this should ideally have got downloaded with installing modules @types/cucumber(In my case it did not get downloaded)
As a temporary solution I copied this "index.d.ts" file from other project and pasted in the node-modules/types location

Comment: Huh?  That is built into Cucumber 6+ isn't it?  It says so in the release notes.  https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/HEAD/docs/migration.md